# Как поставить фоновое изображение на сайт HTML+CSS?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть сайт

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Моя личная страничка в стиле 0х</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Личная страничка Чайки Михаила</h1>
  <p>Выполнена в стиле интернета нулевых</p>
</body>
<style>
  body {
    background-image: url("космос.jpg") fixed center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Я хочу поставить изображение космос.jpg как фон, но почему-то оно не работает. Притом что консоль никаких ошибок 404 не выводит. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот-так:

**background-image: url("./космос.jpg");**

**background-attachment: fixed;**

**background-repeat: no-repeat;**

**background-position: center;**

**background-size: cover;**

Comment: А ещё нужно думаю добавить height: 100vh; к body, так как изображения через стили не влияют на высоту и ширину родителя.